# Why is my table size more than 4x larger than expected? (rows*bytes/row)

Tags: mysql, storage, innodb

I'm looking at a simple table in MySQL that has 4 columns with the following sizes,

```
unsigned bigint (8 bytes)
unsigned bigint (8 bytes)
unsigned smallint (2 bytes)
unsigned tinyint (1 byte)
```

So I would expect 19 bytes/row.

There are 1,654,150 rows in this table so the size of the data should be 31,428,850 bytes (or about 30 megabytes).

But I can see via phpMyAdmin that the data is taking up 136.3 MiB (not including the size of the Index on `bigint 1, smallint, tinyint` which is 79 MiB).

Storage Engine is InnoDB and Primary Key is `bigint 1, bigint 2` (a user ID and a unique item id).

---

**Edit:** As requested in the comments, here is the result of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE storage`

```
CREATE TABLE `storage` (
 `fbid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `unique_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `collection_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `egg_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`fbid`,`unique_id`),
 KEY `fbid` (`fbid`,`collection_id`,`egg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Have you read this?: [InnoDB Physical Row Structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html)

Comment: I hadn't -- will read through that now. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever deleted any rows?

Comment: Marcus - yes, we have.

I think the INSERT/DELETE ratio is much higher than 1 but that's just a gut feeling I have no data handy to support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table is frequently doing insert/delete/update, you may want to try run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` query to see how much the table can get shrink. there may be defragmentations and unused spaces in the data file.

The data size that phpmyadmin shows you won't be what you expected here. You will see when you create the table first time, it won't show data usage : 0. It will be 16KB or 32KB or something. And the size won't change as you insert records. That's just how innoDB controls the table file as efficient as it thinks.

Check `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM {db_name}` and see how much of Avg_row_length each row of the table is. It won't be 19 bytes either

Comment: Wow, that made a large difference, the Data field went from 136MiB to 68MiB after an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. So now it's only about twice the size I expected.

Comment: This works for InnoDB if you're using `--innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you really care the size, MyISAM will be better although it has downside as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your indexes have there own tables on disk (though you can't directly 'see' them).  The total size of your db is the size of your table and index tables.

Run

```
show create table <tablename>;
```

You can see any indexes defined.  Imagine adding the total size of your table and a table consisting of the two columns in your primary key.  Those added, will get you the size you're seeing.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding this. This is what I'm seeing from phpMyAdmin -- "Total" makes sense to me as Data+Index but Data is the one I'm confused about. There's another Index table being counted in there? http://i.imgur.com/TJPTF.png

Comment: @BradDwyer MySQL keeps different copies of parts of your tables for indexes. Total size is size of the table you query against and all of it's internal index tables.  Run the create table and paste the create mysql statement into the question and we can break it down in more detail for you.

Comment: Ray - added `SHOW CREATE TABLE` result to the question

Comment: See the line `KEY `fbid` (`fbid`,`collection_id`,`egg_id`)`, that actually creates on disk another table mysql uses behind the scenes called an index table.  It has the 3 columns fbid, collection_id, and egg_id and the primary key of the original table.  It has the same number of rows as your main table.  MYSQL reports size back for a table as the table size + the size of all associated index tables.

Comment: That makes sense and the numbers appear to more or less add up after the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` suggestion that @mask8 made. So what is the "Index" field listed under "Space Usage" in the screenshot posted above if it's not that table?

Comment: @BradDwyer  I don't use PHPmyAdmin so I'm not really sure... It's probably just letting you know how much of the total is being used in index tables alone...  Add a new index on one of the columns and see how the reported numbers adjust.

Comment: I added a 3-column index on `collection_id, egg_id, unique_id` and the `Data` portion only increased marginally from 69 MiB to 71 MiB but the `Index` portion went from 88 MiB to 132 MiB. So it looks like it is in fact breaking out the `Index` usage vs actual `Data` usage somewhat effectively. Which leaves me confused about what is taking up the extra space in `Data` -- would the Primary Key affect space at all?

Answer (score 2):

The data size for InnoDB on disk is typically 2-3 times as big as you would compute.  This is due to

- Overhead per column (length, offset into record)
- Overhead per row (tx id, etc)
- Overhead per block (16KB) (link to next block -- B+Tree)
- BTree averages 69% full
- MVCC -- Multiple Version Concurrency Control.  That means that there can be old *and* new copies of any row coexisting simultaneously during a transaction
- Etc.

One thing that would help:  Almost no application needs `BIGINT` (8 bytes) for ids.  Consider `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes, 4B limit) or `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes, 16M limit), etc.  You have 2 Bigints, but 4 copies of them -- the secondary key implicitly includes the PK columns.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is stored with the data, so it incurs very little overhead.  The secondary key, which is effectively 4 columns, is a BTree with a similar set of overheads.

Even in MyISAM, there is overhead:

- At least 1 byte per row.  (1 in your case)
- 1 byte per 8 `NULLable` columns (none in your case)
- Some amount of lost space after rows are `DELETEd` or `UPDATEd`.  (Updated won't be a problem in your case, due to `FIXED` record size.)
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is just like any other index
- All keys have the 69% issue; blocks are 1KB

(Since you have no `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`, I don't need to discuss the `CHARACTER SET issues.)

In InnoDB, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is often off by a factor of 2 in the *estimate* of the number of rows.  The Avg_row_length is computed as Data_length / Rows, so it is usually off.

I do *not* recommend `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for InnoDB tables; it is almost always not worth the effort.

When doing `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX ..`, older versions of MySQL would rebuild the entire table and indexes.  In doing so, you get the effect of `OPTIMIZE`.  (It is unlikely, but not impossible, for the Data size to increase.)  Newer versions only add on the new index.  What version are you running?

Each `INDEX` is a separate BTree (except for the PK in InnoDB) (and except for `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`).