# Why is the size of my MySQL database larger than the individual values would indicate?

Tags: mysql

I am storing two columns of unsigned integers (which should be 4 bytes each according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) and I would have expected the size of the table to be roughly around rows * 8 bytes. The individual table files (those with an .ibd extension, correct me if I am thinking of this wrong) start at 96 KB for all of my small tables. As I get into tables with larger numbers of rows, the size grows dramatically and the bytes per row evens out at around 30, as shown here. Rows per table are 2^k and there is a table for each k. The first column is the primary key.

```
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Size k |    Rows    |    KB    |    Bytes    |     B/R     |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|      1 |          2 |       96 |       98304 | 49152       |
|      2 |          4 |       96 |       98304 | 24576       |
|      3 |          8 |       96 |       98304 | 12288       |
|      4 |         16 |       96 |       98304 | 6144        |
|      5 |         32 |       96 |       98304 | 3072        |
|      6 |         64 |       96 |       98304 | 1536        |
|      7 |        128 |       96 |       98304 | 768         |
|      8 |        256 |       96 |       98304 | 384         |
|      9 |        512 |       96 |       98304 | 192         |
|     10 |       1024 |      128 |      131072 | 128         |
|     11 |       2048 |      160 |      163840 | 80          |
|     12 |       4096 |      208 |      212992 | 52          |
|     13 |       8192 |      336 |      344064 | 42          |
|     14 |      16384 |      560 |      573440 | 35          |
|     15 |      32768 |     9216 |     9437184 | 288         |
|     16 |      65536 |    10240 |    10485760 | 160         |
|     17 |     131072 |    12288 |    12582912 | 96          |
|     18 |     262144 |    15360 |    15728640 | 60          |
|     19 |     524288 |    23552 |    24117248 | 46          |
|     20 |    1048576 |    40960 |    41943040 | 40          |
|     21 |    2097152 |    69632 |    71303168 | 34          |
|     22 |    4194304 |   131072 |   134217728 | 32          |
|     23 |    8388608 |   253952 |   260046848 | 31          |
|     24 |   16777216 |   499712 |   511705088 | 30.5        |
|     25 |   33554432 |   995328 |  1019215872 | 30.375      |
|     26 |   67108864 |  1978368 |  2025848832 | 30.1875     |
|     27 |  134217728 |  3948544 |  4043309056 | 30.125      |
|     28 |  268435456 |  7892992 |  8082423808 | 30.109375   |
|     29 |  536870912 | 15773696 | 16152264704 | 30.0859375  |
|     30 | 1073741824 | 31543296 | 32300335104 | 30.08203125 |
|     31 | 2147483648 | 63074304 | 64588087296 | 30.07617188 |
+--------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html and [Why is my table size more than 4x larger than expected? (rows*bytes/row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526734/why-is-my-table-size-more-than-4x-larger-than-expected-rowsbytes-row), I figured out that these tables are stored in the COMPACT format and average length according to the database is around 28 bytes (not 30) for most of the tables.

```
HEADER = 5 + CEILING(N/8) + 1   = 7 bytes // N = 1 NULL field of the 2
TRANSACTION ID FIELD = 6        = 6 bytes
ROLL POINTER FIELD = 7          = 7 bytes
PRIMARY KEY (YES) = 0?          = 0 bytes
ACTUAL DATA (2 UINTS)           = 8 bytes
------------------------------------------
                                = 28 bytes
```

I did a lot of research as I started this question and answered most of my larger size question, but I wanted another set of eyes to make sure I was looking at this right. Also, where are the other 2 bytes coming from?

Comment: Did you include indexes?

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html, the primary key acts as the index, so the 4 bytes for the first column are used.

Comment: *The default size of an index page is 16KB. When new records are inserted, InnoDB tries to leave 1/16 of the page free for future insertions and updates of the index records.* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-physical-structure.html ... 28/30 is suspiciously similar to 15/16.

Comment: How many index pages are we talking, though. Enough to add 2 bytes per row to the overall .ibd file size for that table?